# How to crawl 'this' url use urllib?

Tags: python, download, urllib

I try to use urllib to crawl this file: http://www.anzhi.com/dl_app.php?s=68611, but always download a wrong file(size smaller). However, if I open up this link on chrome, it goes well  and the downloaded file size is correct. The code is attached, what's the problem?

```
import urllib

apk = "http://sc.hiapk.com/Download.aspx?aid=294091"
local=r'x.apk'

webFile = urllib.urlopen(apk)

localFile = open(local, "w")
realurl = webFile.geturl()
print realurl
realFile = urllib.urlopen(realurl)
localFile.write(realFile.read())
webFile.close()
realFile.close()
localFile.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

What OS are you on? This line of code:

```
localFile = open(local, "w")
```

opens a text-mode file on Windows, which will do things that you don't want. Does changing that to

```
localFile = open(local, "wb")
```

(opening the file in binary mode) make things work correctly?

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Johnsyweb: on the contrary, it contains an actionable suggestion that may solve the OP's problem. It is not "Not an answer" simply because it ends with a question mark.

Answer (score 1):

You're not using the same URL in your code that you're asking about in the question. Use the anzhi.com URL and you'll get the file you want. :)